# How to make a html speech button

Tags: html

So am trying to make an html5 speech button 
i want something like that button in Google translate website
http://translate.google.com if you visited the website in chrome you will find a speech to text input the one that Google offers with chrome browsers
so i took a look at the HTML code and i found this

```
  <input id="gt-speech-in" type="text" speech="speech" x-webkit-speech="x-webkit-speech"                
  x-webkit-grammar="builtin:translate" size="1" lang="en" style="" tabindex="-3">
```

which does not output a button like it was in translate.google it just outputs a small text input 
so how can a change it into a button or make it smaller so it can look like a button?

Comment: How does your question relate to javascript, css, python, and PHP?

Comment: I found the answer in another website and it is all about CSS and i was not sure that if is it a javascript , css or html thing plus every one that know php or python must know html thanks for removing my tags but please learn programming before removing tags :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome the snippet above **does** display the input microphone, and you can control the size of the text entry field in the style eg:

```
<input id="gt-speech-in" type="text" speech="speech" x-webkit-speech="x-webkit-speech"                
x-webkit-grammar="builtin:translate" size="1" lang="en" style="width:200px;" tabindex="-3">
```

Are you trying to get anythng additional to display on the form (or get it to work in a non-Chrome environment)?